# Make QWidget disappears after click not on it

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm showing QTableWidget, and want it to disappear after some item in this table was selected and if user clicked outside  QTableWidget area.

```
connect(tableWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTableWidgetItem *)), tableWidget, SLOT(close()));
```

this line do what I want after selecting item. Is it a way of make widget disappears after clicking not on it without  subclassing it (I can subclass and write my own losefocus event handler, for example, but without subclassing would be better)?

Comment: Do you have a surrounding container? Implement an event in there, while your widget is open...

Comment: let's assume, you have MainWidget, that contains everything within it. It has clicked() signal. Connect that to some slot and in that slot hide tableWidget ( tableWidget()->hide() )

Comment: @bash.d based on Ur idea I put QTableWidget into QWidget and made the latter Qt::Popup

Comment: @bash.d yes, exactly as I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to put QTableWidget into QWidget and made the latter Qt::Popup - an it acts exactly how I need

Answer (score 1):

let's assume, you have MainWidget, that contains everything within it. It has `clicked()` signal. Connect that to some slot and in that slot hide tableWidget ( `tableWidget()->hide()` )

Comment: I considered this, but it won't work if user will click outside main widget

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a very elegant solution, but it might work:

1. Subclass `QTableWidget`
2. Make sure that the table widget has the keyboard focus while you display it.
3. Reimplement [`void QWidget::focusOutEvent ( QFocusEvent * event )`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusOutEvent) (close the table widget, when you lose focus)

Comment: yes, about this variant I've wrote in my question and question is can I avoid it =)